# i am trying to connect my jdbc program oracle database 10g and using window 8

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

my code is

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SelectTest{
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        try {
            class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:myDb","system","oracle");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");

            while(rset.next()) {
                System.out.print(rset.getInt(1)+"\t"+rset.getString(2)+"\t"+
                rset.getString(3)+"\t"+rset.getInt(4));
            }//while loop
            con.close();
        }//try 
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(ex);
        }//catch
    }//main 
}//class
```

And i set classpath of the oracle DB in system environment  as

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;.
```

And i set path for jre in user variables as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;.;
```

i am not getting why my program is giving the error:

```
Error: this program is not recognised as internal or external command.
```

Comment: It would be better if you develop your program using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. By the way, please add the command you use to compile this program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't have jre and jdk installed. If `java -version` has the same result install these.

Comment: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin* is the path of JDK 1.7 release 17.

Comment: What is the output from `java -version` ? Did you set the path variable?

Comment: We don't know that because OP hasn't added the command he/she uses when trying to compile the code. That's noted in my comment. But yes, the problem looks like JAVA_HOME variable isn't set on PATH system environment variable.